# How to check if a gridview was interacted with?

Tags: android, gridview

I have created a view called "SkillChooser" that inherits from GridView.
It contains a bunch of skills that I can choose from.
The SkillChooser class has an Internal OnItemClickedListener.

I'm using the SkillChooser in another activity.
In that activity, every time an item is clicked on the skillChooser, I want a certain TextView to be refreshed. All I need is to find a way to check whether or not a certain item (doesn't even matter which!) in the SkillChooser has been clicked. I cannot define an OnItemClickedListener, since it will overrun the existing, internal OnItemClickedListener that the SkillChooser already has. Once I know if the skillChooser has been interacted with, I can call a function which retrieves all chosen skills.

Comment: How about maintaining any boolean or calling an interface in the activity which you have mentioned in the description

Comment: @RaviSravanKumar, let's say I maintain a boolean variable. How do I use it? What do I do?

Comment: can youu post any code so that I can modify and answer